# How to optimize query for super user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, query-optimization, database

I am doing the following query in pseudo code:

- Give me all users in age range (provided by user input)
- User's who have been seen the least recent first (10 at a time)
- User's interest must include one of my interests
- User's who have not been swiped left or right by me

If I swiped through 1,000 users and then someone swiped all the same 1,000 then a new user is added making it 1,001. Since all the other 1,000 have been least recent since each new user gets the most recent being the date they create their account, then it has to go through the 1,000 before getting to 1,001 leading to a 3-4 minute query call which is not ok.

My current stack includes Javascript for my web, Backend uses NodeJs with Mongodb.

The three queries look like this:

```
var minAge = (req.body.min);
var maxAge = (req.body.max);
var swipersCount = 0;
verifyLoginFilter(req, function(loggedIn, userObj, uid) {

    if (loggedIn && !userObj.accountFrozen) {

        //doing -1 on min and +1 on max for inclusive

        var minAgeMinusOne = minAge - 1;
        if (minAge === 0) {
            minAgeMinusOne = 0;
        }
        var maxAgePlusOne = maxAge + 1;
        var theSwipers, swipersInterests;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var skipCount = 0;
        grabSwiperLastSwiped();

        function grabSwiperLastSwiped() {

            User.find({
                "$and": [
                    { accountFrozen: false },
                    { creditsAvailable: { $gt: minAgeMinusOne } },
                    { userId: { $ne: uid } }, {
                        "$or": [
                            { "minAge": { "$lt": maxAgePlusOne, "$gt": minAgeMinusOne } },
                            { "maxAge": { "$lt": maxAgePlusOne, "$gt": minAgeMinusOne } }
                        ]
                    }

                ]


            })

            .limit(10).sort({ dateLastSwiped: 1 }).skip(skipCount).select({ userId: 1, activeInterests: 1, creditsAvailable: 1, dateLastSwiped: 1 })
                .exec(function(err, swipers) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.json({ statusCode: alertErrors.mongodb });
                    } else {
                        if (swipers.length > 0) {
                            theSwipers = swipers;
                            grabSwiperInterests();
                        } else {

                            return res.json({ statusCode: alertErrors.noSwipers });
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        function grabSwiperInterests() {
            var today = new Date();
            var finalMax;

            if (theSwipers[x].creditsAvailable > maxAgePlusOne) {
                finalMax = maxAgePlusOne;
            } else {
                finalMax = theSwipers[x].creditsAvailable;
            }

            Interests.
            find({
                    "$and": [
                        { userId: theSwipers[x].userId },
                        { paused: false },
                        { _id: { $nin: userObj.personSwiped } }

                    ]
                }).limit(10)
                .sort({ dailyCredits: 1 })
                .exec(function(err, interests) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.json({ statusCode: alertErrors.mongodb });
                    } else {
                        if (interests.length > 0) {
                            swipersInterests = interests;
                            checkInterst();
                        } else {
                            nextSwiper();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        function nextSwiper() {
            swiperCount++;
            console.log("nextSwiper " + theSwipers[x].userId + " number " + swiperCount);
            if (x === theSwipers.length - 1) {
                x = 0;
                skipCount = skipCount + theSwipers.length;
                grabSwiperLastSwiped();
            } else {
                console.log("nextSwiper " + theSwipers.length + " x " + x);
                x++;
                grabSwiperInterests();

            }
        }

        function nextInterest() {
            console.log("nextInterest");
            if (y === swipersInterests.length - 1) {
                nextSwiper();
            } else {
                y++;
                checkInterst();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I am open to a PostGres Solution if that makes more sense?

Comment: It's not really clear... Which query is the slowest ? What are your index on `User` and `Interests` collection? What's in your `checkInterst()` function ?